# Writing files to Google App Engine Storage with Go seems to have a 10MB limit?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-storage

I am using http://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/storage#Writer to write files to GAE Storage. Using `io.Copy` returns successful results as long as the size of the file I am trying to copy is less than 10MB.  If the file is greater than 10MB, my `io.Copy` exits successfully with number of bytes written but the file is nowhere to be found in my bucket.

I can't find any pointers in the docs so would appreciate some community feedback on how they're doing this.  Here is my code snippet:

```
func (s *GoogleStorage) StoreReader(r io.ReadCloser) error {
  defer r.Close()

  wc := storage.NewWriter(s.Context, s.Bucket, s.BackupName)
  wc.ContentType = "text/plain"
  wc.ACL = []storage.ACLRule{{storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader}}
  defer wc.Close()

  count, err := io.Copy(wc, r)
  if err != nil {
    s.app.Infof("Error doing copy:", err)
  }
  s.app.Infof("Bytes written: %d", count)
  return err
}
```

I updated the above code to return more information:

```
func (s *GoogleStorage) StoreReader(r io.ReadCloser) error {
  defer r.Close()

  wc := storage.NewWriter(s.Context, s.Bucket, s.BackupName)
  wc.ContentType = "text/plain"
  wc.ACL = []storage.ACLRule{{storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader}}

  count, err := io.Copy(wc, r)
  if err != nil {
    s.app.Infof("Error doing copy:", err)
  }
  if err := wc.Close(); err != nil {
    s.app.Infof("ERROR ", err)
  }
  s.app.Infof("updated object:", wc.Object())
  s.app.Infof("Bytes written: %d", count)
  return err
}
```

And this is the error I get after the `wc.Close()`

```
    I 16:31:19.729 ERROR %!(EXTRA *url.Error=Post https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/maxr-test/o?alt=json&uploadType=multipart: Call error 5: )
I 16:31:19.729 updated object:%!(EXTRA *storage.Object=<nil>)
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, when uploading files larger than 10MB via the web interface, it uploads with no problems.

Comment: Ok, I added some error handling on wc.Close() and I get the following error: ERROR %!(EXTRA *url.Error=Post https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/maxr-test/o?alt=json&uploadType=multipart: Call error 5: )

Comment: Hmm, I found this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/#Go_Quotas_and_limits ~ seems like there is indeed a 10MB limit.  What now?

Comment: A couple of thoughts: (i) what happens if you try to get the object's metadata after the `Copy()` returns ([godoc](http://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/storage#Writer.Close))? And (ii), when you say the file is nowhere to be found, are you trying to _get_ the object or _list_ the bucket contents (see [consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#consistency))

Comment: Hi there, I updated the post to reflect more information and hopefully the answer to your first question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions may be to use [Cloud Storage Java Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries) to upload/write the file in Cloud Storage. The advantage of using that it automatically support resumable/chunk uploads so that you will not fall under that URL Fetch request size exceed error. Here is the [Go example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-go-samples).

Answer (score 0):

It's due to limit on Google Storage 10MB. 
In my logs:

```
com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.RequestPayloadTooLargeException: The request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/XXXXXXXX exceeded the 10 MiB limit.
```

This is what I've found and I'm using  Java lib: (`com.google.api.services.storage.Storage`)

Here I found example by [google](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/storage-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/storage/cmdline/StorageSample.java) however my team mate is still investigating this.

Maybe that would help you. I would add my results when finished.

Ok. Solved. 
MediaHttpUploader.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE is around 10MB and this is already too much. Everything below 10MB would be accepted.

```
    Storage client = getService();
    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = client.objects().insert(
            BUCKET_NAME, objectMetadata, contentStream);

    //done by adding following two lines:
    //  - chunk is set to <10MB (~5MB in this case)
    //  - directed upload is disabled.
    insertRequest.getMediaHttpUploader().setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE/2); //set to 5MB
    insertRequest.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

    final StorageObject storageObject = insertRequest.execute();
```

Maybe this would lead you by analogy to solution in your GO problem

Cheers!